# Create an IEnumerable<> of unrelated EF4 entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

So here's the scenario...My website displays three different types of products for sale. For this example, we'll call them Furniture, Clothes and Toys. The three products are distinctly different, yet all share some of the same properties (Price, DateCreated, Description, ShortDescription, etc).

I'm using EF4 so when I display a list of products on the "Furniture" page, I can just do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Furniture> furniture = Repository.GetFurniture();
```

Everything is working great when I'm only displaying one product type on a page. I have the entire set of Furniture displayed in a paged list of 10 products per page, sortable by Name, Price, Ad Date, etc.

However, I want to create a link to "See all of this seller's products". This page will need to display EVERYTHING the seller has listed regardless of whether it's furniture, clothes or toys. The trick is, it also needs to be sortable by the fields that all of the products share in common (price, name, ad date, etc).

So what I'd like to do is something like this pseudo-code:

```
IEnumerable<IProduct> products = 
Repository.GetAllProducts(sellerId).OrderBy(sortField).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

Then, in the View (yes, I'm referencing EF4 entities in the view):

```
@foreach (var product in Model.products.OrderBy(sortField))
{
    if (product is Furniture)
    {
       Html.RenderPartial("FurnitureResult", (Furniture)product)
    }
    else if (product is Clothes)
    {
       Html.RenderPartial("ClothesResult", (Clothes)product)
    }
    // repeat for toys
}
```

So my question is:

What would the call to Repository.GetAllProducts(sellerId) look like? It would need to be a set of LINQ queries that gets all of the furniture, clothes and toys and combines them into a single IEnumerable<>. If that's not possible, what other methods could I employ to get a list of products like this?

Essentially I just need to know what the best method is to group a set of unrelated objects with some common properties into a single collection and then sort that list by one of the common properties and then determine which concrete class it is as I iterate over them.

Thanks!

Comment: Do your EF classes already implement `IProduct`? Or is achieving this part of the problem?

Comment: Good question. No, they don't at this point.

Comment: Yikes, `if-then` logic on types is an incredible code smell. (Think what happens if you add a fourth type of product?)

Comment: I'm open to other suggestions as to how to accomplish the end goal. The product types used here are just arbitrary examples. The site will never have more than the three I've created already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create the partial classes for each of the entities. The partial class will implement the interface IProduct, which will not be a part of EF, but will have the properties to return price, name, ad date etc.

Implement these properties getters to return specific properties of the entity and implement the method GetAllProducts to return the combined enumerable of all entity types.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a Database View, and adding it to your Context. Otherwise,

```
Repository.GetAllProducts(sellerId).OrderBy(sortField).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

would run in the memory, I mean you'd have to at least execute it on 3 different DbSets, and merge those to get the final set.

Another option is using the Inheritance, make a base Product type, and inherit the 3 different products from it. http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx
Check out all Inheritance options from the above web blog, so there are 2 more blogs to follow up in it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative options:

Union all products in a collecton of type Object so Repository.GetFurniture().Cast().Union(Repository.GetClothes().Cast());

Or: use dynamic and ducktyping and render using common property names. (bleg)